# Combining lines from a text file in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file that outputs lines of the following form:

```
$XYZ blah blah blah
$XYZ something
$XYZ random data
```

The "$XYZ" prefix is the same for every line, it really does start with a dollar sign, and it's highly unlikely to occur anywhere but the start of a line.

The only way I can get at this file is via screen capture, which causes the lines to wrap at 80 characters.  So it looks like the following (if you pretend wrapping is at a smaller number than 80):

```
$XYZ blah bl
ah blah
$XYZ somethi
ng
$XYZ random 
data
```

I'd like to recreate the real lines from that.  I could write a program to do it, but I'm thinking there might be some Unix command that I'm not familiar with that might make it easy.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Crazy security permissions at various levels.  I can do a cat, but I can't ftp it or cp it to somewhere I could ftp it from or anything else that I've been able to think of.

Comment: if you're doing a `cat` in a terminal emulator, aren't the line breaks being inserted client-side, in which case you should be able to pipe the output locally somehow?

Comment: can't you sftp or scp it (channeling it through ssh, that is) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, merge all the lines into one long line and then add a newline wherever you see the word which is supposed to be the start of a line, like this:

```
tr -d '\n' < file | sed 's/XYZ/\nXYZ/g'
```

Comment: i was about to answer with exactly this

Comment: No, but maybe because I'm not doing the regexp correctly... I should have noted that "XYZ" actually begins with a dollar sign.

Comment: use `\$` to escape the dollar i.e. `sed 's/\$XYZ/\n$XYZ/g'`

Comment: @user1738853 Make sure you using *single quotes* with `sed`. Double quotes will cause the shell to interpret `$XYZ` as a variable.

Comment: OK, problem was not the regexp - I was doing that correctly - it was that the file that screencap made had CRLFs, not just LFs.  Stripped the CRs out too, and your suggestion then worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `perl` :

```
perl -pe 's/\n//g;s/XYZ\s+/\n$&/g' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`paste`](http://man.cx/paste) command is for exactly this purpose:

```
paste -d "" - -
```

As in

```
echo '$XYZ blah bl
ah blah
$XYZ somethi
ng
$XYZ random 
data' | paste -d "" - -
```

outputs

```
$XYZ blah blah blah
$XYZ something
$XYZ random data
```